# Valid XML data, but null in the responseXML property in the XMLHttpRequest response

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmlhttprequest

[URL](https://start.vag.de/dm/api/v1/haltestellen/VAG/location?lon=11.06464944&lat=49.4484825&radius=450) returns XML data, but the responseXML property in the XMLHttpRequest response is empty. How can I get the XML data in the response?

```js
document.body.onload = loadXMLDoc();

function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://start.vag.de/dm/api/v1/haltestellen/VAG/location?lon=11.06464944&lat=49.4484825&radius=450", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table = "";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Haltestellen");

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    table += "<tr><td>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("Haltestellenname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("VGNKennung")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td></tr>";

  }
  document.querySelector("#fahrten-tabelle > tbody").innerHTML = table;
}
```

```css
#fahrten-tabelle {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 49px;
  width:100%;
}
#fahrten-tabelle th {text-align:left;}
```

```html
<table id="fahrten-tabelle">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fahrzgnr.</th>
      <th>Linie</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Startzeit</th>
      <th>Ziel</th>
      <th>Endzeit</th>
      <th>Verlauf</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

That API returns json by default from an ajax request.  I know it looks like it always returns XML but you can inspect the return text just prior to calling `myFunction()` and see.  Try setting the format to xml with:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://start.vag.de/dm/api/v1/haltestellen/VAG/location?lon=11.06464944&lat=49.4484825&radius=450&format=xml", true);
```

When I test your code that works for me.

Also, you will probably want to eventually verify some of your assumptions around the xml returned.  Just using

```
x[i].getElementsByTagName("Haltestellenname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

looks rather fragile to me.

```js
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://start.vag.de/dm/api/v1/haltestellen/VAG/location?lon=11.06464944&lat=49.4484825&radius=450&format=xml", true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { myFunction(this); }
    };

    xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table="<tr style='padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:5px;background-color:white;position:sticky;top:49px'><th style='text-align:left'>Fahrzgnr.</th><th style='text-align:left'>Linie</th><th style='text-align:left'>Start</th><th style='text-align:left'>Startzeit</th><th style='text-align:left'>Ziel</th><th style='text-align:left'>Endzeit</th><th style='text-align:left'>Verlauf</th></tr>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Haltestellen");
    for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
        var Haltestellenname = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Haltestellenname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var VGNKennung = x[i].getElementsByTagName("VGNKennung")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        table += "<tr><td>" + Haltestellenname + "</td><td>" + VGNKennung + "</td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("fahrten-tabelle").innerHTML = table;
}


loadXMLDoc();
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" id="fahrten-tabelle"></table>
```

Comment: Oh. I already knew this problem but I didnt see it. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The `xml.responseXML` property (`xml` has type `XMLHttpRequest`) was empty, because the `application/xml` request header was not set. You need either to read the `response` property, or set the valid request header with [setRequestHeader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader) function.

> The *XMLHttpRequest* method *setRequestHeader()* sets the value of an HTTP
>   request header. When using *setRequestHeader()*, you must call it after
>   calling *open()*, but before calling *send()*. If this method is called
>   several times with the same header, the values are merged into one
>   single request header.
>
> Each time you call *setRequestHeader()* after the first time you call
>   it, the specified text is appended to the end of the existing header's
>   content.
>
> If no Accept header has been set using this, an Accept header with the
>   type *"*/*"* is sent with the request when *send()* is called.

```js
document.body.onload = loadXMLDoc();

function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://start.vag.de/dm/api/v1/haltestellen/VAG/location?lon=11.06464944&lat=49.4484825&radius=450", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/xml');
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table = "";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Haltestellen");

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    table += "<tr><td>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("Haltestellenname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("VGNKennung")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td></tr>";

  }
  document.querySelector("#fahrten-tabelle > tbody").innerHTML = table;
}
```

```css
#fahrten-tabelle {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 49px;
  width:100%;
}
#fahrten-tabelle th {text-align:left;}
```

```html
<table id="fahrten-tabelle">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fahrzgnr.</th>
      <th>Linie</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Startzeit</th>
      <th>Ziel</th>
      <th>Endzeit</th>
      <th>Verlauf</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did my answer help to solve the problem, @Peter Stadler?